# Using Celery/RabbitMQ/Flower in deployment with Django Website

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, pythonanywhere, cloud-hosting

I have a django website that utilizes celery scheduling async tasks. When I am in development mode, I run the commands:

```
celery -A proj worker --pool=solo -l INFO
flower -A proj --port:5555
celery -A proj beat -l info
```

for my project to work. How can I run these commands on a cloud based hosting service such as pythonanywhere. In development I would go to localhost and port number to view rabbitmq and flower. How will this work in deployment?

Answer (score 0):

That would not work on PythonAnywhere. There are other ways to do async in web apps there. https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AsyncInWebApps/